# rails 4 delete link not working inside namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i use rails 4 and

"Delete") + "Delete",admin_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },:remote=>true %>

not working inside namespace. It behaves like show link

Answer (score 1):

I think, Your 'jquery_ujs' is not working properly. Please check your application.js manifest file in assets/javascripts directory. add the following line under //require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs

Answer (score 0):

this is my application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

i don't think it's about this since it works in any controller out of namespace